# Logging from multi processes corrupt file?

Tags: python, logging, gunicorn, python-logging

I use **Django** served through **gunicorn** with four **gevent** workers and have some logging configuration, specially it uses `RotatingFileHandler`. The python documentation states that:

> Although logging is thread-safe, and logging to a single file from multiple threads in a single process is supported, logging to a single file from multiple processes is not supported, because there is no standard way to serialize access to a single file across multiple processes in Python.

Therefore in my current config there's only one parent process for **gunicorn** and has some threads so the logging should not corrupt the file, but in my production I got backup files corrupted but could not reproduce the situation in my local setup.

Should I assume that the config is fine and continue using it or should I go for a different approach (e.g. `multiprocessing.Queue` or `SocketHandler`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have four event workers, that means there are four distinct processes doing request handling and logging - so you should probably use `SocketHandler` as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network). I usually use [`Supervisor`](http://supervisord.org/) to run the listener process.

Comment: **gevent** workers use different processes for listening? I thought **gunicorn** start a master process and the spawn as many workers of **gevent** as needed.

Comment: @MaskedMan Yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunicorn

Comment: Oh thanks, glad to see you here (author of python logging package!) 